# Play Game Services Get other player profile picture

Tags: android, google-play-services, profile-picture

I've recently added Google Play services to my game and merged new players score with my old leaderboard with Facebook users. So I have one common leaderboard for everybody. (That's why I can't use Google's built in leaderboard).

Within the game I show the leaderboard with profile picture and score of the player. 
My problem is when trying to retrieve Google users profile image for leaderboard. I've found examples but all of them show current user profile not for any given google id.
Reading games documentation I've found `Games.Players.loadPlayer()` and implemented it.

I tried the following code and works but only for some players (I assume players within circle of logged in account)

```
//mGoogleApiClient = Connected GoogleApiClient
//uid = Google User ID (Got from Games.Players.getCurrentPlayerId(mGoogleApiClient())
//mImageView = Destination imageView

Games.Players.loadPlayer(mGoogleApiClient, uid).setResultCallback(new theResultCallback<Players.LoadPlayersResult>() {
@Override
public void onResult(@NonNull Players.LoadPlayersResult loadPlayersResult) {
    ImageManager imgMGr = ImageManager.create(getActivity());
    if (loadPlayersResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
        imgMGr.loadImage(mImageView, loadPlayersResult.getPlayers().get(0).getIconImageUri());
    }
});
```

This code is working but only with players in circle. When player is not in circle I get:

```
Status{statusCode=STATUS_NETWORK_ERROR_NO_DATA, resolution=null}
```

I couldn't find in the documentation nothing about permissions or requirements to get other players profile image other than 
Required API: API
Required Scopes: **`SCOPE_GAMES`**.
And I have both enabled in my GoogleApiClient.
[Google Documentaion on LoadPlayer()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/Players)

Does anybody knows other way to get profile picture of google user if you have the ID?

Is it possible or this images are not public? (But Google's built in leaderboard shows them...)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm have not yet implemented or tried but if you are not using the built-in leadership board by Google, try using the [Retrieve profile information for a signed-in user](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/people) to get the userPhoto of the account. Use the [GoogleSignInResult.getSignInAccount](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInResult.html#getSignInAccount()) method to request profile information for the currently signed in user.

Comment: Hi, I can retrieve logged in user profile picture, and with method described I can also retrieve the profile picture of people in the circles of the logged in user. My problem is retrieving users pictures that do not share circles with currrently logged in user.